# Python, TCP, Server and client

Tags: python-3.x

I have problem with TCP (Server and Client.) over python3.
What does i do wrong?

my code is in TCP Server:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = socket.gethostbyname("127.0.0.1")
port = 8892
address=(ip,port)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(1)
print("[*] Started listening on" , ip, ":", port)
client,addr = server.accept()
print("[*] Got Connection from", addr[0], ":", addr[1])
while True:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    data = data.decode('utf-8')
    print("[*] Received ", data, " from the client")
    print("[*] Processing data")
    if data == "hello":
        client.send("Hello client")
        print("[*] Processing done\n[*] Reply sent")
    elif data == "disconnect":
        client.send("Goodbye")
        client.close()
        break
    else:
        client.send("Invalid type")
        print("Processing done Invalid data \n[*] Reply sent")
```

my code is in TCP Client:

```
import socket

client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = socket.gethostbyname("127.0.0.1")
print(ip)
port=8892
address=(ip,port)
client.connect(address)

while True:
    message = input()
    client.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    print(client.recv(1024))
```

Erorr message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tcpServer.py", line 25, in
>   
>       client.send("Invalid type") TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Can some one help me please, what can i do?

Thanks for helping me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python 3 you are no more sending/reading characters or string, but byte-array (or bytes).

You might also need to manage encoding (utf-8 <-> bytes).

ex:

```
>>> s = "énorme"
>>> b = s.encode("utf-8")
>>> b
b'\xc3\xa9norme'
```

and use the bytes.decode() to reverse it.

For your very trivial case, you can use direcly bytes string as `b"hello"`, as plain ASCII string are converted "as-is" to bytes.

`client.send("Hello client")` will become `client.send(b"Hello client")`

But don't go too deeper with this solution. 
I personally allow this usage when using commands to talk to some hardware, but absolutely not for a chat or text exchange.